# Use a viewmodel with web api action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I just read this post by Dave Ward (http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/), and I'm trying to throw together a simple web api controller that will accept a viewmodel, and something just isn't clicking for me.

I want my viewmodel to be an object with a couple DateTime properties:

```
public class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }
```

Without changing anything in the stock web api project, I edit my values controller to this:

```
public IEnumerable<float> Get()
    {
        DateRange range = new DateRange()
        {
            Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            End = DateTime.Now
        };

        return Repo.Get(range);
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public IEnumerable<float> Get(DateRange id)
    {
        return Repo.Get(range);
    }
```

However, when I try to use this controller, I get this error:

`Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Single] Get() on type FEPIWebService.Controllers.ValuesController
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Single] Get(FEPIWebService.Models.DateRange) on type FEPIWebService.Controllers.ValuesController`

This message appears when I hit

```
/api/values
```

or

```
/api/values?start=01/01/2013&end=02/02/2013
```

How can I solve the ambiguity between the first and second get actions?

For further credit, if I had this action

```
public void Post(DateRange value)
{
}
```

how could I post the Start and End properties to that object using jQuery so that modelbinding would build up the DateRange parameter?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in detail described here: [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection). The Extract

With that background, here is the action selection algorithm.

> 1. Create a list of all actions on the controller that match the HTTP request method.
> 2. If the route dictionary has an "action" entry, remove actions whose name does not match this value.
> 3. Try to match action parameters to the URI, as follows:
>
>    - For each action, get a list of the parameters that are a simple type, where the binding gets the parameter from the URI. Exclude
>        optional parameters.
>    - From this list, try to find a match for each parameter name, either in the route dictionary or in the URI query string. Matches are
>        case insensitive and do not depend on the parameter order.
>    - Select an action where every parameter in the list has a match in the URI.
>    - If more that one action meets these criteria, pick the one with the most parameter matches.
>
> 4.Ignore actions with the [NonAction] attribute.

Other words, The **ID** parameter you are using, is not **SimpleType**, so it does not help to decide which of your Get methods to use. *Usually the Id is integer or guid..., then both methods could live side by side*

If both of them would return `IList<float>`, solution could be to omit one of them:

```
public IEnumerable<float> Get([FromUri]DateRange id)
{
    range = range ?? new DateRange()
    {
       Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
       End = DateTime.Now
    };
    return Repo.Get(range);
}
```

And now both will work

```
/api/values
```

or

```
/api/values?Start=2011-01-01&End=2014-01-01
```

Comment: Succinctly answered, I finally understand now why Get(int id) could sit happily next to Get(), but Get(DateRange id) cannot.

Comment: Good if that helped. The link I've provided is really good one. Good luck ;)